# Sudoers NOPASSWD for single executable but allowing others

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, gnu, sudoers

Operating System: `Arch Linux`

Linux version: `4.16.11`

Sudo version: `1.8.23`

**What I need**:

- be able to execute `any executable` with a `sudo` with a password prompt
- be able to execute one executable, `/home/username/script.sh`, without a password prompt.

When I configure like this

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/username/script.sh
```

I have the desired effect on the `script.sh`, but I cannot execute any other `executable` with `sudo`.

Example

```
$ sudo ./script.sh # runs fine!
```

Attempt something other

```
$ sudo nano /etc/sudoers
[sudo] password for username: 
Sorry, user username is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/nano 
/etc/sudoers' as root on hostname.
```

Seems this is a result of replacing `ALL` with `NOPASSWD`, and seems I need both.
If the `sudoers` file has `ALL` for the user, I can execute whatever I want with password prompt

```
username ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I tried to combine ALL and NOPASSWD but had no results

```
username ALL=(ALL) ALL, NOPASSWD: /home/username/script.sh
```

Like this it asks for password for `script.sh`.

Can I have both?

Comment: Please note that if the user has write permissions on the file, he can bypass the password check easily by editing it. The `NOPASSWD` options should be used for executables that can't be changed by the users, like, say `ifconfig` for a network admin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`man 5 sudoers`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) says ("Sudoers File Format" section):

> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order. Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific match).

So you should have these lines exactly in this order:

```
username ALL=(ALL) ALL
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/username/script.sh
```

and any line that also matches (like e.g. `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`) should be before the `NOPASSWD` line.

General note: `#include` and `#includedir` allow `sudoers` to include *other files*. From the version 1.9.1 the encouraged directives are `@include` and `@includedir` respectively, but `#include` and `#includedir` are still accepted. Don't let `#` fool you, these are *not* comments. While searching for entries that may interfere, you shouldn't omit what `#include` and `#includedir` point to. Helpful option: `sudo -l`.

Answer (score 3):

You will often find a line like this in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%wheel   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

This will allow any user that is in the "*wheel*" group to make use of `sudo` with suitable proof of identity (e.g: their password). The nominated group may also be "*sudo*", "*admin*", or others... (e.g: line starts with `%sudo`)

If this is present in the file, then run `id` to see what groups you're in:

```
$ id
uid=1000(attie) gid=1000(attie) groups=1000(attie),27(sudo),117(docker)
```

If your user isn't in the appropriate group, then you must add your user to that group.

---

An alternative would be to list both of your rules one-by-one, with the last matching rule taking effect (i.e: order is important):

```
username ALL=(ALL) ALL
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/username/script.sh
```

See the ArchWiki page on sudo: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo#Example_entries

Comment: Thank you. Though you answered first, Kamil was the first to provide the answer that suits me better, thus accepted answer is Kamil's.