# macOS: pkill a specific process without sudo?

Tags: macos, bash, bluetooth, process, sudo

Because of some recent bluetooth issues, I need to be able to run `sudo pkill bluetoothd` quite frequently, so I decided to create a shell script Shortcut to have on my menu bar for quick access. I usually need to run this command in urgent situations, so I hope you can understand typing in my password or waiting for Touch ID to finally recognise my finger can become annoying very quickly.

At first I thought to use blueutil as it doesn't require sudo, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work the same (it reconnects to my devices slower than terminating bluetoothd), so unless there's a way to make blueutil faster I want to avoid using it.

Then I considered modifying my sudoers file to make pkill runnable without sudo, but it sounds like a huge security risk doing that. Because of this, I thought of creating a .command file and specifying it in my sudoers file, but I'm afraid the file can be edited without privileges, again creating a big security risk.

I'm looking for the best way to do this, but if there's a method to either make bluetoothd killable without sudo, or to make a .command file executable but non-writeable, do let me know.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Then I considered modifying my `sudoers` file to make `pkill` runnable without `sudo`, …

You cannot use `sudoers` to make something runnable without `sudo`. `sudoers` is relevant if and only if `sudo` is involved. You can use `sudoers` to make something runnable with `sudo` *without password*.

> … but it sounds like a huge security risk doing that.

It depends on how you do it.

- If you allow `pkill` without password then yes, you will allow `pkill` and `pkill anything`, and also `pkill anything and_more …`.
- If you allow specifically `pkill bluetoothd` without password then you will allow only `pkill` with exactly one argument `bluetoothd`; you won't allow `pkill something_else`, not even `pkill bluetoothd something_more`.

A relevant line in `sudoers` will look like this:

```
arber ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/pkill bluetoothd
```

The point is `sudo pkill foo` or `sudo pkill bluetoothd foo` will still ask for your password (unless they match another `NOPASSWD` rule or your credentials are being cached).

When building your `sudoers`, remember that [where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific match).](https://superuser.com/a/1328457/432690)

---

> […] but I'm afraid the file can be edited without privileges, again creating a big security risk.

If you use the above solution then you won't need such file.

*In general*, if you ever need such file, then create the file as owned by root, writable only by its owner, in a directory owned by root and writable only by its owner. Allow other users to read and enter the directory; allow other users to read and (if you want) execute the file.

Example: the directory and the file in it are owned by `root:wheel`. The mode for the directory is `755`, the mode for the file is `755`. One can edit or overwrite or remove or replace such file only when acting as root.